# S3 Amazon Multi-Part Upload InputStream content messed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inputstream

We started working with S3 Amazon Multi-Part Upload. We are sending InputStream in Java Application working under tomcat.

1. Where can I find a working example of Multi-Part Upload to S3 using Input Stream (and not File)?
2. I stripped down our code to demonstrate the problem. It seems that we upload 2 parts consisting of certain patterns (digits), but after completing upload to Amazon the full object contains different content.

Code test uploading 2 byte[] and downloading the full content afterwards.

```
@Test
    public void AmazonWay(){
        final long partSize = 5*1024*1024; // 5 MB
        byte[][] multi = new byte[][]{
                AmazonAdaptor.initArray((byte)1, (int)partSize),
                AmazonAdaptor.initArray((byte)2, (int)partSize)
        };

        try {
            String filePathOrig = getTempPath("D:\\temp\\", "orig");
            writeArraysToFile(multi[0],multi[1], filePathOrig );    
            ContentData contentData = storage.multiPartExampleSend2BigParts(multi);             
            byte[] retrieveAllBytes = new byte[(int)(partSize*2)];     
            contentData.getInputStream().read(retrieveAllBytes);                
            String filePath = getTempPath("D:\\temp\\", "fromAmazon");
            writeBytesToFile(filePath, retrieveAllBytes);               
            byte[] part1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(retrieveAllBytes, 0, (int)partSize);
            byte[] part2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(retrieveAllBytes, (int)(partSize+1), (int)(retrieveAllBytes.length));             
            Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(multi[0], part1));
            Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(multi[1], part2));              

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Amazon Exception - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The method below receives an array of byte arrays and uploads them to S3 using the Java SDK. After completing the multi-part upload the method tries to retrieve the full object and return the full object content.

So the Test will be able to compare the merged Object content
consists of sum of uploaded parts.

```
public ContentData multiPartExampleSend2BigParts(byte[][] multi) throws Exception{
        final long partSize = 5*1024*1024; // 5 MB    
        String existingBucketName = bucketNameDefault;
        String keyName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // Create a list of UploadPartResponse objects. You get one of these
        // for each part upload.
        List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();

        // Step 1: Initialize.
        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new 
             InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
        InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = 
                amazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

        String uploadId = initResponse.getUploadId();
        String eTagComplete = null;
        String eTagRetrieve = null;
        try{    
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            for (int iPart = 0; iPart < multi.length; iPart++) {
                byte[] part = multi[iPart];                 
                //partSize = part.length;                   
                // Create request to upload a part.
                ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(part);                  
                UploadPartRequest uploadPartRequest = new UploadPartRequest().withBucketName(existingBucketName)
                .withKey(keyName)
                .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
                .withPartNumber(iPart+1)
                .withPartSize(partSize)
                .withInputStream(inputStream)
            ;
                // Upload part and add response to our list.
                System.out.println(String.format("Starting upload Part-%d, Size=%d",(iPart+1), part.length));

                partETags.add(
                        amazonS3Client.uploadPart(uploadPartRequest).getPartETag());

                System.out.println(String.format("End upload Part-%d, Size=%d",(iPart+1), part.length));
            }

            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest request = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(existingBucketName, keyName, uploadId, partETags);
            CompleteMultipartUploadResult amazonResult = amazonS3Client.completeMultipartUpload(request);

            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
            S3Object s3object = amazonS3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
            S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();          
            long objectDataSize = s3object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength();
            String contentType = s3object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType();
            String amazonTag = s3object.getObjectMetadata().getETag();

            byte[] retrieveBytes = new byte[(int) objectDataSize];
            inputStream.read(retrieveBytes);
            ContentData data = new ContentDataImpl(inputStream, objectDataSize);

            return data;                
         } catch (Exception e) {
                amazonS3Client.abortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest(
                        existingBucketName, keyName, initResponse.getUploadId()));                  
                throw e;
        }
    }

public static byte[] initArray(byte value, int size){
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        Arrays.fill( bytes, value );
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: please include the output (what you see with 'println').

Comment: how is the object different then you would expect?

Comment: Output:Starting upload Part-1, Size=5242880
End upload Part-1, Size=5242880
Starting upload Part-2, Size=5242880
End upload Part-2, Size=5242880

Comment: The received buffers have 0 padding

starting from some position

Comment: First object is expected to consist of 
01 01 01 ...

When got back it starts as 
01 01 01 ...
....
But at some point it goes
00 00 00 ...
...